# The flagged Queue is not updating correctly

Tags: bug, flagging

When looking at [Flagged Queue](https://askubuntu.com/tools/flagged), and after flagging some or all the questions/Answers, the number of flags stays the same, or increases, when the number of flagged items decrease, or done all together.

Images below, are taken at different intervals showing what's going on.  This has been going on for about a day or so.

[image]
[image]
[image]

### ----------

[image]

### ----------

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should now be fixed; please let me know if you're still seeing inconsistencies.

Comment: Still some issues.  The added images shows that there is only 5 items, but the flag count shows 11.  See last image above.  this is from about 30 min ago.