# Use different colors for the flag indicator and the suggested edit indicator

Tags: feature-request, design, 10k-tools

The flag indicator and the suggested edit indicator look exactly alike, they can only be distinguished by their position (from left to right: flags, “review”, suggested edits).

[image: Ask Ubuntu screenshot]

Most other sites use a different color, often yellow for flags and brown for suggested edits. Just to make things worse, the indicators are in a different order on beta sites!

[image: beta screenshot]

Please use different colors for the two indicators on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I've never been bothered by this until you mentioned it. :P

Comment: I have noticed it can be a bit confusing.

Comment: Man... I love that suggested edit indicator. *must. get. 10k. rep.*

Answer (score 2):

I do agree with that.  I find my self clicking on the wrong one from time.  So having different colors for each is a good idea.  Plus the fact that the review flag queue is still out of sync.  See this [post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6939/the-flagged-queue-is-not-updating-correctly).

Comment: What colours do you suggest?

Comment: Well Orange/Yellow or Red/Yellow